# What should i do to maintain performance of a mobile app which is using database?

Tags: ios, sql, performance, search, scale

I'm building an app using database.
I have a `words` table and everytime user types something, this app will record and update word the database.

And the `frequency` field will be auto increase after user enter one matched word.

But the trouble is user type day by day and i afraid the search performance will be reduce after times and also the Int field will reach to the limit (max limit Int) someday.

So, i limit the database to around less than 50.000 records.
I delete less-used records after a certain time.

But i don't know how to deal with `frequency` Int field of each word?
How to know exactly frequency usage of each word without increasing the field forever?

Comment: Is this database going to live on the device or on a server?

Comment: @DanBracuk database will be stored on the device. that is why i don't want it to be too big

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use a logarithmic scale for the frequency values. That's what is often done in situations like this. [See Wikipedia to learn about logarithmic scales](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale).

For example, if you have a word MAN that has a frequency of 15, the value you store in the database would be log(15) ~= 1.17609125906.

If you then find 4 new occurrences of MAN, then you want to add 4 to the field. You cannot add the log values directly because log(x)+log(y)=log(x*y).  ([See the Logarithm Rules section of this article for more information on log rules](http://www.rapidtables.com/math/algebra/Logarithm.htm).)

Instead -- assuming you use a base 10 logarithm, you would use this formula:
SET frequency = log(10^frequency+4)

Comment: By this way, technically, it helps to minimize the frequency number only. I can change frequency field to float and every time i used a word, i increase it with 0.1 or 0.01. It also make this field small, but the SQLite sorts Float field is slower than Int field. Moreover, the number is still increasing. Any algorithm to calculate the frequency field by percent of usage, i think it might be better in this case.

Comment: Did you understand the idea about a logarithmic scale?

Comment: I'm reading about logarithmic scale. But if i store `1.17609125906` number to the database, with this long string number it'll take more time for sorting query. Simply storing an integer gives the best performance of sorting.

Comment: The logarithmic scale idea doesn't work. By the time an integer type would overflow, your float stops incrementing. Just try to compute `1e33 + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the length of your words, the few bytes for the frequency don't matter. With an unsigned four bytes integer, you can count up to more than two billion, which is way above the number of words what the user can type in in their whole lifespan.

So may want to go for two or three bytes, but the savings may be negligible.

---

Anyway, there are the following approaches for preventing overflow:

- You can detect it, and then undo the operations, scale everything down by some factor of two, and then redo.
- You can periodically check all your numbers and do the scaling when approaching the limit.
- You can do a probabilistic update like below.

#### Probabilistic update

Instead of simply incrementing the frequency every time by one, you do it only with a probability which gets lower and lower as the counter grows. For example, you can do the increment with a probability of `1.0 / (oldValue + 1)` or `2 ** -oldValue`. The latter leads to a logarithmic growth, but, unlike the idea in the other answer, it works.

There are obviously some disadvantages due to the randomness and precision loss, but when all you care about is the relative frequency, it should be good enough.